# JSF: calling javascript code from Managed Bean not working when forcing page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I need to execute a **JavaScript** code from a JSF **Managed Bean**'s method that is basically to click a button on a facelet (.xhtml file). All this works perfectly by using PrimeFaces'   **RequestContext.execute("{js here}")**, however it no longer works when adding some 'page reload' code lines by using **ExternalContext...** (please see code below). It seems like the 'page reload' lines prevented the JavaScript code from executing. Any hints is welcome !

```
public void myMethod() throws IllegalStateException, Exception {

    RequestContext rc = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();.           

    rc.execute("$('#myButton').click();");

    try {
        ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        ec.redirect(((HttpServletRequest) ec.getRequest()).getRequestURI());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error", e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RequestContext is for the current request, a redirect is a another request. it can't work.

Try to do something like this:

```
RequestContext rc = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
rc.execute("$('#myButton').click(); window.location = newURL;");
```

Comment: **Hi Rostislav**, thanks for your hint ! just a question: since I need to reload the same page, shouldn't I use **window.location.reload(true)** ?

Comment: I think that you have a method call is triggered by click some button, so try to turn of AJAX and page will reload automatically.

For primefaces buttons use ajax="false" attribute.

Comment: Hi Rostislav, thanks, I will give it a try. Best Eduardo

Comment: @ekremer: please accept the answer. It is correct and valid. Other users can find it easier then